# Run Java .class file from another class file (more specific)

Tags: java, class

I would like to run AsyncPlayerChatEvent.java inside adminchat.java, specifically when person types command /ac it would use AsycPlayerChatEvent.java to handle it. ive googled it but it doesnt seem to work out, i tried adding               AsyncPlayerChatEvent.AsyncPlayerChatEvent(); but it didnt work, here's the code.

adminchat.java

```
    package alo.adminchat;

import java.util.IllegalFormatException;
import java.util.Set;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Cancellable;
import org.bukkit.event.HandlerList;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerEvent;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class adminchat extends JavaPlugin
{

     @Override
        public void onEnable()
     {
         System.out.println("Adminchat by Alo k2ivitus!");
            // TODO Insert logic to be performed when the plugin is enabled
     }

        @Override
        public void onDisable()
        {
            System.out.println("Adminchat by Alo sulgus!");
            // TODO Insert logic to be performed when the plugin is disabled
        }
        public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args)
        {
            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("achelp"))
            { // If the player typed /ac then do the following...
                // doSomething
                return false;
            } //If this has happened the function will return true. 
                // If this hasn't happened the a value of false will be returned.
            return false; 
        }
        public boolean onCommand2(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args)
        {
            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ac"))
            { // If the player typed /ac then do the following...
                AsyncPlayerChatEvent.AsyncPlayerChatEvent(); //This is what needs fixing
                 return true;
            } //If this has happened the function will return true. 
                // If this hasn't happened the a value of false will be returned.
            return false; 
        }


}
```

AsyncPlayerChatEvent.java

```
package alo.adminchat;

import java.util.IllegalFormatException;
import java.util.Set;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Cancellable;
import org.bukkit.event.HandlerList;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerEvent;

 public class AsyncPlayerChatEvent extends PlayerEvent implements Cancellable {
     private static final HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
     private boolean cancel = false;
     private String message;
     private String format = "<%1$s> %2$s";
     private final boolean recipients;


     public AsyncPlayerChatEvent(final boolean async, final Player who, final String message, final Set<Player> players) {
         super(who, async);
         this.message = message;
        recipients = player.hasPermission("adminchat.use");
     }

     public String getMessage() {
         return message;
     }

     public void setMessage(String message) {
         this.message = message;
     }

     public String getFormat() {
         return format;
     }

     public void setFormat(final String format) throws IllegalFormatException, NullPointerException {
         // Oh for a better way to do this!
         try {
             String.format(format, player, message);
         } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
             ex.fillInStackTrace();
             throw ex;
         }

         this.format = format;
     }

     public boolean getRecipients() {
         return recipients;
     }

     public boolean isCancelled() {
         return cancel ;
     }

     public void setCancelled(boolean cancel) {
         this.cancel = cancel;
     }

     @Override
     public HandlerList getHandlers() {
         return handlers;
     }

     public static HandlerList getHandlerList() {
         return handlers;
     }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run a `.class` file"? `AsyncPlayerChatEvent` isn't a main class (no `main` method), and you can't "run" a non-main class.

Comment: any way i could fix this? sorry im new to java

Comment: Tell us specifically what you're wanting to do with `AsyncPlayerChatEvent`. Based on the code you posted, it's really just a data object (like a C++ `struct`) that doesn't do anything interesting on its own. Are you trying to create one that you will then send to some other service in the player?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so when you execute command /ac [msg] it sends message out but only to the players with permission adminchat.use.

Comment: First, it's standard for classes to start with a capital letter, so you ought to rename your class to AdminChat (though that's not a technical requirement). I'm guessing that you need to create an `AsyncPlayerChatEvent` as described in the answers, and then call some method in the plugin API to send the event.

Comment: my brain will definetly not figure it out, as im too fresh to java, im not sure what specifically i have to learn about java to do it properly...

Answer (score 3):

I think what you mean is you want create an instance of AsyncPlayerChatEvent?

```
new AsyncPlayerChatEvent();
```

But you need to pass in your arguments:

```
boolean async, Player who, String message, Set<Player> players
```

Comment: says the constructor AsyncPlayerChatEvent() is undefined. sorry, im new to java :(

Comment: Yes, you need to pass in the arguments required to call the constructor. See the 2nd line of code I posted.

Comment: Gives me a list of syntax errors, if i do new AsyncPlayerChatEvent(boolean async, Player who, String message, Set<Player> players); .

Comment: I think we need to find you a tutorial. You're not quite understanding what I'm saying. the prefix before each is the CLASS TYPE of the argument, the first required argument is a Boolean, so you need to enter either TRUE or FALSE, the second argument is the Player class, the 3rd is a String and the last is an array of the Player class.

Comment: Most likely, yes, I did not understand it right now as well.. can i ask for your skype ?

Comment: We can use the stack overflow chat.

Comment: need 20+ rep to talk in chatrooms

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the constructor with `AsyncPlayerChatEvent.AsyncPlayerChatEvent()`, you should use `new AsyncPlayerChatEvent()` instead. This will create a new `AsyncPlayerChatEvent` and call the constructor on it.

Comment: says the constructor AsyncPlayerChatEvent() is undefined. sorry, im new to java :(

Comment: @tbodt took a typing shortcut that confused you. The constructor statement is going to be something like `new AsyncPlayerChatEvent(true, currentPlayer, textStringAfterAc, setOfPlayersWithPrivilege);`. The arguments get passed to the `APCE` constructor.